# Writting in a textarea inside a (xcode) WebView, causes the view to being pushed up

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, html

Here is the scenario. I'm developing an app for ipad. This app, is just a container for a web site. I created a webview that calls a website which has a textarea.

If I click inside this textarea and the softkeyboard is displayed, the view is pushed up more than the size of the keyboard. I fixed this by using the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification notification to put the view down again.

But check this. If I write inside the textarea, the view is pushed up again, even if is just one letter.

Here are some screenshots:

this is before writting something

[image: this is before writting something]

this is after writting something

[image: this is after writting something]

Has somebody had the same issue? Or any clue of what is hapenning?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure it out. It was my fault, the cause was that the main view was a TableView. Changed to a simple View and everything is now perfect